# get th count from table and details from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables one contain the next

```
___________________________________
||         Hospital Table        || 
||_______________________________||
|| Hospital_no  || Hospital_name ||
||                               ||
```

and the other

```
___________________________________
||     Doctor Table              ||
||_______________________________||
|| Doctor_no    || Hospital_no   ||
||                               ||
```

which doctor.Hospital_no linked with Hospital.Hospital_no
and i wont to get

```
______________________________________________________
|| Hospital_name | number of doctors in the hospital
||                                                  ||
```

how can i do that

Comment: That's very very basic SQL. JOIN the tables GROUP by Hospital id and name and COUNT the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select HP.Hospital_name,COUNT(DT.Doctor_no) as
NoOfDoctors
 from HospitalTable HP
Left join DoctorTable DT
ON HP.Hospital_no=DT.Doctor_no
GROUP BY HP.Hospital_name
```

Comment: thanks that's work after i add the (group by HP.Hospital_name) at the end , but it gave me the hospitals with doctors , the problem is i have hospitals with no doctors doesn't show

Comment: @AlareesSamer please some sample data

Comment: thanks man a lot , i have used (left join) instead join and it work's

Comment: @AlareesSamer Yeah...I updated... Left Join Gives Matching Records from both table as well as All records from Left Table ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT H.Hospitel_name , 
       count(*) "#Doctors"
FROM 
Hospital H 
INNER join 
Doctor D 
ON 
(H.Hospitel_no = D.Hospitel_no)
GROUP BY H.Hospitel_name ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

well i did not check it but its looks like what you want (use `cross apply`)

```
SELECT Hospital_name,count( Doctor_no    )
FROM Hospital 
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT  Doctor_no 
FROM Doctor  d
WHERE Hospital.Hospital_no  =  Doctor.Hospital_no ) x
```